# Java close PDF error

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have this java code:

```
try {
    PDFTextStripper pdfs = new PDFTextStripper();

    String textOfPDF = pdfs.getText(PDDocument.load("doc"));

    doc.add(new Field(campo.getDestino(),
            textOfPDF,
            Field.Store.NO,
            Field.Index.ANALYZED));

} catch (Exception exep) {
    System.out.println(exep);
    System.out.println("PDF fail");
}
```

And throws this:

```
11:45:07,017 WARN  [COSDocument] Warning: You did not close a PDF Document
```

And I don't know why but throw this 1, 2, 3, or more.

I find that COSDocument is a class and have close() method, but I don't use this class nowhere.

I have this imports:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: The resource type `PDDocument` does not implement `java.lang.AutoCloseable` so we can't go with try with resource for current scenario.

Comment: Maybe you're using an old version of PDFBox. In 2.0.13 it is Closeable which extends AutoCloseable. Btw this is not an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're loading a `PDDocument` but not closing it. I suspect you need to do:

```
String textOfPdf;
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load("doc");
try {
    textOfPdf = pdfs.getText(doc);
} finally {
    doc.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet, this code solved 100% the problem, thanks :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet I use pdfbox in .net programming, I close 'doc' but the Error There is still! what can I do?

Comment: @AmirHossein: it sounds like you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 8):

Just had this issue, too. With Java 7 you can do this:

```
try(PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(input)) {
  // do something  
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Because `PDDocument implements Closeable`, the `try` block will automagically call its `close()` method at the end.

Comment: btw, try-with-resources exists since Java 7.

Answer (score 5):

This warning is emitted when the pdf document is finalised and hasn't been closed.

Here is the `finalize` method from [COSDocument](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/cos/COSDocument.java):

```
/**
 * Warn the user in the finalizer if he didn't close the PDF document. The method also
 * closes the document just in case, to avoid abandoned temporary files. It's still a good
 * idea for the user to close the PDF document at the earliest possible to conserve resources.
 * @throws IOException if an error occurs while closing the temporary files
 */
protected void finalize() throws IOException
{
    if (!closed) {
        if (warnMissingClose) {
            log.warn( "Warning: You did not close a PDF Document" );
        }
        close();
    }
}
```

To get rid of this warning, you should explicitly call `close` on the document when you are done with it.

Comment: Thanks dogbane, but I don't know if I don't understand your answer.
Anyway, I don't use COSDocument in any codeline, so I don't think that's the problem... :)

Comment: @bonsai The `PDDocument.load` method creates a `PDDocument` which has an underlying `COSDocument`. So you are implicitly using a `COSDocument` which needs to be closed. If you close the `PDDocument`, the underlying `COSDocument` is closed too.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody using Kotlin, the extension function *use* takes care of any Closable for you:

```
val textOfPdf = PDDocument.load("doc").use { pdfs.getText(it) }
```

cf. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html