# Pdf process is not closing even after closing the Pdf in Java

Tags: java, pdf

I searched for [Java close PDF error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968491/java-close-pdf-error) but this dose not solve my issue. In my case the logic works fine with newer versions of adobe reader but when it comes to older versions, whenever I try to print a `PDF` file, I have to close the adobe process in the task manager before opening new document. I am not sure what to update.

### My code :

```
finally{

    try {
        doc.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: You have to kill the Process via the command line. Use something like Powershell's `Get-Process` command to query the PID of the Adobe Reader process and pipe into `taskkill /pid pid#`

Comment: What is your "doc" variable an instance of?  Can we see a complete code sample?

Comment: PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();

Comment: @andredleach that is with commands anything i can do in the code..?